# What is the best open source ecommerce solutions?

Tags: e-commerce

basic features are fine, but, must beable to update and customise in terms of look and feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

Magento is customizable, but not ideal for small e-commerce websites, since it has fairly big hardware requirements to work.

Prestashop has some messy code and follows strict rules related to the layout, wich makes it kind of hard to change.

I've been exploring OpenCart, and despite his "youngness" (sorry if this is not a word), it follows the MVC pattern for both frontend and backend, along with OOP, wich makes it easy to change. Also, his default backend UI is more user-friendly that the other 2 I mentioned. Still, wont put my hands on the fire for it, since I never tried to build anything over it, just checked out his coding practices.

Comment: thanks mate, i'll have a look at all of them.

Comment: @WANNABE: meanwhile other good solutions popped up, like Vendor for Kohana Framework, although it's still under development, but very promissing.

Answer (score 0):

There is [PrestaShop](http://www.prestashop.com/). 
According to their FAQ it is licensed under [OSLv3.0](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php).

Comment: prestashop has messy code and the layout follows strict rules, wich often becomes a problem

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) is skinnable and has lots of modules, including  shopping carts, product catalogs, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I think [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products).

Comment: Thats not an ecommerce solution: "Qt is a cross-platform application and UI framework"